# Source for: Abstaining from sin being considered a mitzvah in Talmud Bavli

Tags: sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara, mitzvah, sin, talmud-bavli

I remember seeing a passage in Talmud Bavli saying something along the lines of: "every moment that a person sits and does not engage in sin, he is considered to be doing a mitzvah." I'm not able to find it again and looking for the tractate and the page.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Kiddushin 39b:](https://www.sefaria.org/Kiddushin.39b.15?lang=bi)

> רמי רב טובי בר רב קיסנא לרבא תנן כל העושה מצוה אחת מטיבין לו עשה אין לא עשה לא ורמינהי **ישב ולא עבר עבירה נותנים לו שכר כעושה מצוה** אמר ליה התם כגון שבא דבר עבירה לידו וניצול הימנה
>
> Rav Tuvi bar Rav Kisna raises a contradiction to Rava and asked: We
>   learned in the mishna that anyone who performs one mitzva has goodness
>   bestowed upon him. This indicates that if one actually performed the
>   mitzva, yes, he is rewarded, but if he did not perform the mitzva, no,
>   he does not receive a reward. He raises a contradiction based on the
>   following statement: **If one sits and does not transgress, he receives
>   a reward as one who performs a mitzva**, despite the fact that he does
>   not actually perform a mitzva. Rava said to him: There, when it is
>   referring to one who sits and does not transgress, it does not mean
>   that he was merely sitting; rather, it is speaking of a case where an
>   opportunity to commit a sinful act presents itself to him and he is
>   saved from it.

Comment: And this is a quote from [Makkot 3:15](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Makkot.3.15?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he)